# How can the GeoKeyDirectoryTag byte string be decoded from a las header vlrs?

Tags: las, laspy, python-3.7

I am currently reading a .las file with laspy and transforming the points to a custom state plane coordinate system.  I would like to update the GeoKeyDirectoryTag but cannot find information on how it is encoded.

The sample I have results in the following:

```
User ID LASF_Projection  
Record ID 34735 
Description = GeoKeyDirectoryTag (mandatory)
VLR_body = 

b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x04\xb1\x87(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x01\x08\xb1\x87\x0c\x00P\x00\x02\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x03\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x04\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00+#\x06\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x8e#\x08\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\t\x08\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x08\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x01\x00\x0c\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x8e#\r\x08\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x01\x0c\xb1\x87(\x00(\x00\x02\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x03\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x04\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00+#\x08\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x04\x00\t\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x03\x00\n\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x05\x00\x0b\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x06\x00\x14\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x07\x00\x03\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00+#'
```

Whitebox tools decoded this as:

```
VLR 0:
Reserved: 43707 User ID: LASF_Projection Record ID: 34735 Record After Length: 208 Description: GeoKeyDirectoryTag (mandatory) VLR Data: [1, 1, 0, 25, 1024, 0, 1, 1, 1025, 0, 1, 2, 1026, 34737, 40, 0, 2048, 0, 1, 32767, 2049, 34737, 12, 80, 2050, 0, 1, 32767, 2051, 0, 1, 32767, 2052, 0, 1, 9003, 2054, 0, 1, 9102, 2056, 0, 1, 32767, 2057, 34736, 1, 0, 2059, 34736, 1, 1, 2060, 0, 1, 9102, 2061, 34736, 1, 2, 3072, 0, 1, 32767, 3073, 34737, 40, 40, 3074, 0, 1, 32767, 3075, 0, 1, 1, 3076, 0, 1, 9003, 3080, 34736, 1, 4, 3081, 34736, 1, 3, 3082, 34736, 1, 5, 3083, 34736, 1, 6, 3092, 34736, 1, 7, 4099, 0, 1, 9003]
 
GeoKey Info:
Version: 1
Key revision: 1.0
GTModelTypeGeoKey (code=1024): ModelTypeProjected
GTRasterTypeGeoKey (code=1025): RasterPixelIsPoint
GTCitationGeoKey (code=1026, type=ASCII): NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 18N / SurveyFoot
GeographicTypeGeoKey (code=2048): Unrecognized value (32767)
GeogCitationGeoKey (code=2049, type=ASCII): NAD83(2011)
GeogGeodeticDatumGeoKey (code=2050): Unrecognized value (32767)
GeogPrimeMeridianGeoKey (code=2051): Unrecognized value (32767)
GeogLinearUnitsGeoKey (code=2052): 9003
GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey (code=2054): Angular_Degree
GeogEllipsoidGeoKey (code=2056): Unrecognized value (32767)
GeogSemiMajorAxisGeoKey (code=2057, type=Double, count=1): [6378137.0]
GeogInvFlatteningGeoKey (code=2059, type=Double, count=1): [298.257222101]
GeogAzimuthUnitsGeoKey (code=2060): 9102
GeogPrimeMeridianLongGeoKey (code=2061, type=Double, count=1): [0.0]
ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey (code=3072): Unrecognized value (32767)
PCSCitationGeoKey (code=3073, type=ASCII): NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 18N / SurveyFoot
ProjectionGeoKey (code=3074): Unrecognized value (32767)
ProjCoordTransGeoKey (code=3075): CT_TransverseMercator
ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey (code=3076): Linear_Foot_US_Survey
ProjNatOriginLongGeoKey (code=3080, type=Double, count=1): [-75.00000000024367]
ProjNatOriginLatGeoKey (code=3081, type=Double, count=1): [0.0]
ProjFalseEastingGeoKey (code=3082, type=Double, count=1): [1640416.6666666667]
ProjFalseNorthingGeoKey (code=3083, type=Double, count=1): [0.0]
ProjScaleAtNatOriginGeoKey (code=3092, type=Double, count=1): [0.9996]
VerticalUnitsGeoKey (code=4099): Linear_Foot_US_Survey
```

CODE that decodes and then encodes the bytestring.

```
#!\usr\bin\env\python3
import struct
bytstr = b'\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x04\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x00\x02\x04\xb1\x87(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x01\x08\xb1\x87\x0c\x00P\x00\x02\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x03\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x04\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00+#\x06\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x8e#\x08\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\t\x08\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x08\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x01\x00\x0c\x08\x00\x00\x01\x00\x8e#\r\x08\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x01\x0c\xb1\x87(\x00(\x00\x02\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00\xff\x7f\x03\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x04\x0c\x00\x00\x01\x00+#\x08\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x04\x00\t\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x03\x00\n\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x05\x00\x0b\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x06\x00\x14\x0c\xb0\x87\x01\x00\x07\x00\x03\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00+#'
b_array = []
i_array = []
count = len(bytstr)
print(count)

for i in range(0, count, 2):
    lit = bytstr[i:i+2]    
    item = struct.unpack('H', lit)[0]
    print(item, ' = ', lit)
    i_array.append(item)
    b_array.append(item.to_bytes(2, byteorder='little'))
#new_ba = bytearray(b_array)
print(b_array)
encoded = struct.pack("<{}H".format(len(i_array)), *i_array) #Little Endian
print(encoded)
```

Does anyone know how this data is coded and how to get the info unpacked?   I have tried a few different byte conversions.

It looks like [whitebox-tools](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/blob/master/src/lidar/vlr.rs) may provide some clues.
There is a brief explanation and example from [maptools.org](http://geotiff.maptools.org/spec/geotiff2.4.html).
I better document is on the [OGC GeoTiff Standard](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/19-008r4/19-008r4.html#Summary_of_GeoKey_IDs_and_names)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224052/what-is-the-difference-between-a-string-and-a-byte-string

Comment: Thanks JRR but not really.  I am trying to find a specification on how to get things like 'GeogEllipsoidGeoKey' from the bytestring.  I have tried to convert the whole line and parts of the string.  There are no numbers that match any of the numbers in the results.

Comment: Include a link to your file and the code you used.